# Can't connect to the correct COM port in FreePIE

Tags: python, arduino

I'm trying to run a code in FreePIE (Free Programmable Input Emulator), which is a software that recognizes sensors or extra hardware to enable them as an input in your computer.

Well, the code I'm trying to run is in python:

```
def update():
   global yaw
   global roll
   global pitch
   
   yaw = ahrsImu.yaw
   roll = ahrsImu.roll
   pitch = ahrsImu.pitch
   
   vireioSMT.yaw = yaw - cyaw
   vireioSMT.roll = roll - croll
   vireioSMT.pitch = pitch - cpitch

   diagnostics.watch(yaw-cyaw)
   diagnostics.watch(roll-croll)
   diagnostics.watch(pitch-cpitch)
   
if starting:
   cyaw = 0
   croll = 0
   cpitch = 0
   ahrsImu.update += update

center = keyboard.getPressed(Key.Z)

if center:
   cyaw = yaw
   croll = roll
   cpitch = pitch
```

When I try to run it this error pops up:
[image: Error]

Well, in the software there is no serial configuration, the COM3 actually doesn't exist and there is nothing connected to it, there is only my Arduino in COM6, which would be the correct one to be running this code, but I can't get it to link with it.

I have tried adding this piece of code to the if starting:

```
port = SerialPort("COM6", 115200)
port.Open()
```

Nothing changed, same problem.

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that this code was using the class "vireioSMT" which is a plugin for FreePIE available at:
https://github.com/Baristan6/VireioSMT

If the .dll is added to FreePIE this error will no longer occur, instead it will correctly work.